# Error converting covariance to correlation using scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, correlation, covariance

I am trying to convert a covaraince matrix (from scipy.optimize.curve_fit) to a correlation matrix using the method here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/correlation-matrix-from-covariance-matrix

My test data is from here https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2010/12/10/converting-between-correlation-and-covariance-matrices.html

My code is here

```
    import numpy as np

    S = [[1.0,  1.0,  8.1],
         [1.0, 16.0, 18.0],
         [8.1, 18.0, 81.0] ]

    S = np.array(S)
    diag = np.sqrt(np.diag(np.diag(S)))
    gaid = np.linalg.inv(diag)
    corl = gaid * S * gaid
    print(corl)
```

I was expecting to see `[[1.   0.25 0.9 ], [0.25 1.   0.5 ], [0.9  0.5  1.  ]]` but instead get `[[1. 0. 0.], [0. 1. 0.], [0. 0. 1.]]`.  I am obviously doing something silly but just not sure what so all suggestions gratefully received - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you've probably figured it out by now but you have to use the @ operator for matrix multiplication in numpy. The operator * is for an element-wise multiplication.
So

```
corl = gaid @ S @ gaid
```

gives the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thaks Philippe - had still not found the answer.  Never knew that I had to use the @ operator rather than * for np matrices - you learn something every day!

Answer (score 1):

This is just for the future in case someone else wants a complete response for converting from correlation to covariance and the question asked, which is, from covariance to correlation. Let's use some test data below:

```
import numpy as np

# the correlation matrix
r = np.array([
      [1, -0.48, -0.42, -0.31, -0.37], 
      [-0.48, 1, 0.42, 0.55, 0.61],
      [-0.42, 0.42, 1, 0.35, 0.45],
      [-0.31, 0.55, 0.35, 1, 0.55],
      [-0.37, 0.61, 0.45, 0.55, 1]
      ])

# the std deviations
stdev = np.array([[1.86, 1.81, 0.87, 3.28, 4.18]])
```

The following function converts from correlation matrix to covariance matrix:

```
# cor to cov
def cor2cov(c, s):
    """
    Return a covariance matrix given a correlation matrix 
    and standard deviations.
    : c = covariance matrix
    : s = standard deviation
    """
    D = np.diag(s)
    return D * c * D
    
a = cor2cov(c=r, s=stdev)
print(a)
```

The function below converts from covariance matrix to correlation matrix

```
# cov to cor
def cov2cor(c):
    """
    Return a correlation matrix given a covariance matrix. 
    : c = covariance matrix
    """
    D = 1 / np.sqrt(np.diag(c)) # takes the inverse of sqrt of diag.
    return D * c * D

# print(cov2cor(a))
print(cov2cor(c=a))
```